# Splitting variable not working in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am trying to split the variable based on delimiter. How can I achieve it?

```
  some_module: {{item}}.split('@')[1]
  with_items:
     - git@someversionxxx
     - gradle@someversionxxx
```

I get following error:

> list object' has no attribute 'split ansible

I want to consider only first part of variable i.e. before '@'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
some_module: "{{ item.split('@')[0] }}"
```

- `{{ ... }}` is used to indicate Jinja2 expressions and everything you have is a Jinja2 expression
- with YAML syntax in Ansible you must quote a string if it starts with `{` (unless it was a JSON object, here it's not)
- the first element of the `split` result will have an index of 0